# What books are recommended for the ethics of veg*nism?

Tags: veganism, ethics

Which books are recommended for the ethics of veganism/vegetarianism?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to our site! However, recommendation questions are off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Riker SO had this kind of questions in it's beginnings, and now most of them make very good references (e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)... maybe this could be temporarily allowed around here too, so we could build our own lists of references?